# I get a failure to resolve 'proxy' error on running apt-get update on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dns, ip-address, ubuntu-16.04, apt-get

When I run `apt-get update` on `Ubuntu 16.04` after setting a static ip, I get

```
Err:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'xx.Xx.Xx.Xx'
```

`Xx.Xx.Xx.Xx` is my proxy server address.

But the update works fine when on dynamic allocated ip.

Please help.

Comment: While in static IP config, can you browser a website or `ping google.com`? If fails, then check `/etc/resolv.conf` if there is any valid IP address in the 'nameserver' line. If not, try to set 'name server x.x.x.x' where `x.x.x.x` is your router internal IP address.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried that and the update gets stuck at '0% Working'.

Comment: Ok I got it. I was setting the wrong DNS nameservers. Thanks.

Comment: Great to know the problem solved. I have post the answer based on the comment above. Could you `tick` the answer under the down arrow at the left to close the question? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error message `Temporary failure resolving 'xx.Xx.Xx.Xx'` tells the website domain name `http://archive.canonical.com/` is not able to resolve as IP address so that not able to download the package `xenial`.

You may check name server config file `/etc/resolv.conf` if there is any valid DNS server setup.  In normal case, there will be a valid IP address in the 'nameserver' line. If not, try to set 'name server x.x.x.x' where x.x.x.x is your router internal IP address.